# Auto-generate excel file - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am sitting with an issue relating to VBA in excel - i have been trying to search for a solution but is unable to find one.

I have a global report that is continuously updated with site locations and data on a global scale - the report showcase the pipeline for the upcoming fiscal year. However, the German locations require an additional separate report containing the same data + historical data (previous updates to the global report).

Currently, this is a manual effort, copy pasting data from one report to the other - so my question is. Is there a way to auto-generate and auto-update the German excel file, based on the global excel file continuously adding new sites and updating the local file? And if so, how? I assume the solution would be related to VBA and macros, but this is not my strongest side.

Thank you in advance!